# Why functional index should be dropped before altering the column size

Tags: sql, oracle

Why functional index should be dropped before altering the column size.

Comment: Are you seeing ORA-30556 error functional index is defined on the column to be modified? Oracle enforces functional indices are dropped when altering the structure of any column

Comment: Yes i get this error.

Comment: We have an alternate way in Oracle and that's the following:

1//First Disable the index. (ex: ALTER INDEX index_cust ON CUSTOMER DISABLE)

2//Then alter the column size of Customer table

3// Then Enable the index. (ex: ALTER INDEX index_cust ON CUSTOMER REBUILD)

Note : And this is valid only for functional indexes

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question was haunting my curiosity for a long time. Though i found a [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15098/why-does-it-take-a-long-time-to-drop-a-function-based-index-in-oracle) question which answers this directly, the 'why' part of the question needed more explanation.

Based on [oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS00505), following are the points which mandates the function based index to be dropped:

1. A function-based index computes the value of an expression that involves one or more columns and stores it in the index.
2. Oracle Database represents the index expression as a virtual column, on which the ANALYZE statement can build a histogram.
3. A function-based index precomputes and stores the value of an expression.

The above points emphasize that, the value computed from function itself is stored (as virtual column). So, any DDL on the actual table column, with function-based index, will require rebuild(DML) on [virtual expression](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/oracle-11g-new-feature-virtual-column/) which is not allowed.